# In non commutative rings, which conditions guarantee that left ideals are equal to right ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In Group Theory, a subgroup $N$ is normal if and only if left and right cosets of $N$ are equal. Are there any similar theorems for left and right ideals in Ring Theory?

Comment: Even given more context there is probably no good answer. The only single condition that I'm aware of that applies to all rings is: "commutative." Having right and left ideals coincide is equivalent to left and right ideals all being two sided ideals. Such rings are called **duo rings**. I can only think of one other nontrivial sufficient set of conditions that yield duo rings.

Comment: It seems you completely understood my question. I am not sure how to make it more clear.